# Adding two loops to an elevator system?

Tags: java, loops

So I'm creating an elevator system to go with another piece of code. The system currently works fine, however I would like to add a while loop, so that when an invalid floor is selected, I am given the chance to retry another floor at this point in the code;

```
public static void selectFloor() {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int newFloor;

        System.out.println("Enter your destination floor >>> ");
        newFloor = scnr.nextInt();
        if (newFloor > 7 || newFloor < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid floor entry");
        }
```

I also wanted to add another loop to the system so that once a floor has been selected and the elevator arrives at the destination floor, the cycle will allow the user to select another destination from the current floor in a never ending cycle. Here is the remainder of the code;

```
        else {  
            int direction = 0;
            if(currentFloor < newFloor){
                direction = 1; 
            } else if (currentFloor > newFloor) {
                direction = -1; ;
            } else {
                direction = 0; 
            }
            for (; currentFloor != newFloor; currentFloor += direction)
                System.out.println("..." + currentFloor);
                System.out.println("Elevator has arrived!");
        }
    }

    public void fireAlarm() {
        System.out.println("***FIRE ALARM*** Please exit the building safely.");


}

}
```

Due to the structure of my code, I can't figure out how to do this. How could I add these two loops?

Comment: I think you have an error in your for-loop. Shouln't it be currentFloor += direction?

Comment: You don't need two loops, one should do it.

Comment: @Harmlezz Yes it should, my mistake, thank you!

Comment: Have a look at my answer. The code is not as clean as it could be, but perhaps something you may take to continue your work. Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously need one loop that will loop forever until a break signal from keyboard input is sent (let's say that is number `-1`)

```
public static void selectFloor() {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int newFloor= 0; //initalize to 0

    while (newFloor != -1) { //loop forever until user gives -1 as input
        System.out.println("Enter your destination floor >>> ");
        System.out.println("To exit the programm enter: -1"); //tell the user how to exit
        newFloor = scnr.nextInt();
        if (newFloor > 7 || newFloor < 0) {
           //if logic
        } else {  
           //else logic
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try it this way:

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
int newFloor;
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter your destination floor >>> ");
    newFloor = scnr.nextInt();
    if (newFloor >= 0 && newFloor <= 7) break;
    System.out.println("Invalid floor entry");
};

int direction = Math.signum(newFloor - currentFloor);
while (currentFloor != newFloor) {
    currentFloor += direction;
    System.out.println("..." + currentFloor);
}
System.out.println("Elevator has arrived!");    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach. I broke the whole interaction up into three methods: The first "tells the story". The second handles the input of the new floor and the third takes the elevator to the destination floor. Thus each method has a clear responsibility and can be altered at a later stage if needs be.

```
// Handles the whole thing
public static void elevatorAction() {
    int currentFloor = 1;
    int destinationFloor;

    while(true) {
        destinationFloor = selectNewFloor();
        goToDestinationFloor(currentFloor, destinationFloor);
        System.out.println("The elevator has arrived");
        currentFloor = destinationFloor;
    }
}

// Handles the traveling
public static void goToDestinationFloor(int currentFloor, int destinationFloor) {
    int increment;

    if(currentFloor == destinationFloor) {
        return;
    }

    increment = (currentFloor < destinationFloor? 1: -1);
    while(currentFloor != destinationFloor) {
        currentFloor += increment;
        System.out.println("..." + currentFloor);
    }
}

// Lets the user select a new destination floor for the elevator
public static int selectNewFloor() {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tempNewFloor;

    System.out.println("Please choose your destination floor.");
    while((true) {
        tempNewFloor = scnr.nextInt();
        if(tempNewFloor < 0 || tempNewFloor > 7) {
            System.out.println("Next floor: " + tempNewFloor);
            break;
         } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input: Please choose a floor between 1 and 7");
        }
    }
}
```